# Bind Html.DropDownList

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, html.dropdownlistfor

In my Employee table, fields are like EmployeeID, FirstName, MiddleName, LastName ,... like that.

I want to bind my Html.DropDownList like EmployeeID as dataValueField and FirstName+MiddleName+LAstName as dataTextField. How can I bind like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Create a partial class and set a property like this

    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", FirstName, MiddleName, LastName);
        }
    }

Give 'Name' as the dataTextField
```